connecting to postgres database from azure function - fails with local build/GH actions, succeeds from cli remote build
This question is about the right way to set up/build an azure function such that it'll connect to a postgres database leveraging github actions CI/CD.
How things work
import os
import azure.functions as func
import logging

import psycopg2

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="ping_db", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def ping_db(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    sample_sql = "SELECT * FROM table limit 1;"

    cnx_str = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING")
    with psycopg2.connect(cnx_str) as cnx:
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sample_sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{result}")


@app.route(route="sanity_check", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def sanity_check(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    return func.HttpResponse("sanity_check")

requirements.txt:
azure-functions
psycopg2-binary

Remote Build From Dev Machine
With the above, a remote build from cli func azure functionapp publish <func-app-name> --build remote works just fine.
How Things Don't Work
Local Build
deploying the above with func azure functionapp publish <func-app-name> --build local though gets the following error:

There was an error restoring dependencies. ERROR: cannot install psycopg2_binary-2.9.9 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported when building locally. Use the "--build remote" option to build dependencies on the Azure Functions build server, or "--build-native-deps" option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish

Github Actions
The below is the default github actions created by the azure portal when I integrated the CI/CD pipeline
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/azure/functions-action
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions
# More info on Python, GitHub Actions, and Azure Functions: https://aka.ms/python-webapps-actions

name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - dig-data-functions

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - my_branch
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.9' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_67E3A84100BC4DF68179EAC07489636F }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_AFCA8CC613004EC3B0C8708766E6472B }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_D8A4D5D5E65F4F2986E1BAC1BDD79A92 }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'my-app-name'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          

For some reason, however, when deployed with a github action, there is no error (the job is green), but no functions are functional or visible through the azure web portal, even though the right files are there.
Noting, this is specifically when the line include psycopg2 (and dependent code) is commented in - if this is commented out, the sanity_check works just fine.

I have implemented the same in my environment and able to deploy the function using GitHub actions:
Code Snippet:
import logging
import os

import azure.functions as func
import psycopg2

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="ping_db", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def ping_db(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    sample_sql = "SELECT * FROM <table_name>;"

    with psycopg2.connect(
    host='<postgre_server>',
    dbname='<databasename>',
    user='<username>',
    password='<password>',
    sslmode='require') as cnx:
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sample_sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{result}")


@app.route(route="sanity_check", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def sanity_check(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    return func.HttpResponse("sanity_check")

requirements.txt:
azure-functions
psycopg2-binary

local output:

Application settings of the function app:

GitHub Workflow:
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - <web_app_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.9' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: '<web_app_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_22BDXXXXX3A2F }}



Deployed Successfully:


Portal:

ping_db:

sanity_check:


can you point out what was the key change that made it work?

I have created Function App with Python 3.11.

Deploy your function through Function App=>Deployment Center in portal.

I have constraints requiring python 3.9, further, the deployment is via the GH action

You can select GitHub as Source in Deployment center. It automatically creates the workflow to deploy the function using GitHub actions

Also check the application settings in your function app, if you have all the settings as mentioned in the screenshot.

I could deploy the same to Python 3.9 Function App as well. I have removed the application setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = <URL> and added SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=1 and ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD=1 in the Function App=>App Settings in portal.

@JoeyBaruch, Are you able to deploy the app?

Yes, although I can't find a specific change to attribute the success to
